# Is it grammatically correct to use noun after "in order to"

Tags: grammar

For example;

> I suggest you to edit your question and state what exactly your question is in order to the question to be opened.

Is using a noun after *in order to* in such a sentence grammatically correct ?

Comment: If you do something *in order to X*, ***X*** will always be a ***verb*** (and it's ***to X*** because that's normally how we use "infinitive" verbs).

Comment: @Leth _Suggest_ reveals the subjunctive here, and takes the _bare infinitive_ in that usage: "I suggest (that) you _edit_ your question..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sentence quoted is grammatically incorrect. It should state "[in order *for*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-order-for-something-to-happen) the question to be opened."

This is most likely an error in editing: The writer starts with "... in order to open the question" decides to rephrase, but fails to change the "to" to a "for".

Comment: Could you provide some reference about using "in order for" because I never heard something like it, and it sounds awkward to me.

Comment: @Leth - Here's a quick reference; http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/in-order-for-something-to-happen  It's pretty standard usage.

Comment: The "for" allows for the infinitive to have a subject ("the question") http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-order-for-to.2318054/

Answer (score 1):

[image]
These images are from a book about figure of speech which was published in 1854.

In order to +noun

Not in order for+noun

[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to ELL! Interesting. Could you also include in your answer the title of the book and its author's name?